# Removing Empty DataFrame Objects in Zipped DataFrame Tuple

Tags: python, pandas

Given an input list of times and values that have been indexed based on Time, as shown in the Dataframe, df:

```
>>> df
                       Value
Times
2017-05-10 01:05:03        1
2017-05-10 01:05:00        2
2017-05-10 01:05:10        3
2017-05-10 01:08:12        8
2017-05-11 08:30:20        4
2017-05-11 08:30:14        5
2017-05-11 08:30:35        6
```

I then grouped the times by Minute using the following command:

```
>>> g = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('min'))
```

I then zipped this new dataframe using the following command:

```
>>> (zip(*g)[1])
```

But now, since I grouped by minute, I have multiple empty dataframes.  I want to group by minute so that I can iterate through each minute, but here's my question:  How do I remove Empty DataFrames that are created, when there's no minute to group?  An example output looks like this:

```
Index: [], Empty DataFrame
Columns: [  Value]
Index: [], Empty DataFrame
Columns: [  Value]
Index: [], Empty DataFrame
Columns: [  Value]
Index: [],                        Value
Times
2017-05-11 08:30:14        5
2017-05-11 08:30:20        4
2017-05-11 08:30:35        6
```

Ideally, I would like to have a dataframe with sub-data frames that only include entries that are not empty.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Was your intent to have `g = df.groupby(...)`?  Also, do you intend to apply an operation to the data that is grouped?  Like sum, or mean, or something else?

Comment: yes, edited.  With the data that's grouped, I do intent to apply an operation to the data that's grouped, specifically extracting a maximum value from one of the columns in each group.  That's the next step, but I just want to clean up these different groups first.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this do it for you?

**Setup:**

```
import pandas as pd
import io

c = io.StringIO(u'''
Times,Value
2017-05-10 01:05:03,1
2017-05-10 01:05:00,2
2017-05-10 01:05:10,3
2017-05-10 01:08:12,8
2017-05-11 08:30:20,4
2017-05-11 08:30:14,5
2017-05-11 08:30:35,6
''')

df = pd.read_csv(c, parse_dates = ['Times']).set_index('Times')
```

**Solution:**

```
g = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('min')).max().dropna()

x = (zip(*g)[1])
```

Comment: Yes!  This does work.  I incorporated the last line, x = (zip(*g)[1]) from another script, but I don't fully understand it.  when I print x, I get the following:
`('  ',)`
Also, what does the 1 in the brackets do?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it works. The *g is basically doing a reverse zip and therefore the [1] is getting all second items out of the unzipped list (or tuple in this case).  Beyond that... I'm not really sure quite honestly.  I'd refer back to the solution from where you found that!

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks again mate.